# StackOverflowError on Hibernate Save

Tags: java, hibernate, one-to-many, composite-key, stack-overflow

I have a Student table with an auto generated id as primary key and one to many mappings to Phone table.

My Phone table has a composite primary key PhonePK with phone number and the foreign key id to the Student table.

If I just do student.setPhones and not do phonepk.setStudent, its complaining about **id cannot be null**. So I am setting student.setPhones and phonePk.setStudent. But now I am getting a stackoverflow error on toString.

I really don't like setting it on both ways in the first place but don't know how to get around the id cannot be null error. I've been asking lot of people but they could not help. Could someone take a look please?

**Student.java**

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;

@Entity
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Student implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int id;

private String fName;

private String lName;

private String mName;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "id")
private Set<Phone> phones;

/**
 * @return the fName
 */
public String getfName() {
    return fName;
}

/**
 * @return the id
 */
public int getId() {
    return id;
}

/**
 * @return the lName
 */
public String getlName() {
    return lName;
}

/**
 * @return the mName
 */
public String getmName() {
    return mName;
}

/**
 * @return the phones
 */
public Set<Phone> getPhones() {
    return phones;
}

/**
 * @param fName
 *            the fName to set
 */
public void setfName(final String fName) {
    this.fName = fName;
}

/**
 * @param id
 *            the id to set
 */
public void setId(final int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

/**
 * @param lName
 *            the lName to set
 */
public void setlName(final String lName) {
    this.lName = lName;
}

/**
 * @param mName
 *            the mName to set
 */
public void setmName(final String mName) {
    this.mName = mName;
}

/**
 * @param phones
 *            the phones to set
 */
public void setPhones(final Set<Phone> phones) {
    this.phones = phones;
}

/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
@Override
public String toString() {
    return String.format("Student [id=%s, fname=%s, lname=%s, mname=%s, phones=%s]",      
id,
        fName, lName, mName, phones);
}

}
```

**Phone.java**

```
import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.EmbeddedId;
import javax.persistence.Entity;

@Entity
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Phone implements Serializable {

@EmbeddedId
private PhonePK PK;

private String color;

/**
 * @return the color
 */
public String getColor() {
    return color;
}

public PhonePK getPK() {
    return PK;
}

/**
 * @param color
 *            the color to set
 */
public void setColor(final String color) {
    this.color = color;
}

public void setPK(final PhonePK pK) {
    PK = pK;
}

/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
@Override
public String toString() {
    return String.format("Phone [PK=%s, color=%s]", PK, color);
}

}
```

**PhonePK.java**

```
import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Embeddable;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;

@Embeddable
@SuppressWarnings({ "serial" })
public class PhonePK implements Serializable {

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private Student student;

private String phoneNumber;

public String getPhoneNumber() {
    return phoneNumber;
}

public Student getStudent() {
    return student;
}

public void setPhoneNumber(final String phoneNumber) {
    this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
}

public void setStudent(final Student student) {
    this.student = student;
}

/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
@Override
public String toString() {
    return String.format("PhonePK [student=%s, phoneNumber=%s]", student, phoneNumber);
}

}
```

**Main.java**

```
import java.util.LinkedHashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class Main {

 public static void main(final String args[]) {

    Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
    Transaction transaction = null;

    configuration.addAnnotatedClass(Student.class);
    configuration.addAnnotatedClass(Phone.class);
    configuration.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
    SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory();
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();

    Student student = new Student();
    student.setfName("Bob");
    student.setlName("Buster");

    Set<Phone> phones = new LinkedHashSet<Phone>();
    Phone phone = new Phone();
    phone.setColor("Black");
    PhonePK phonePK = new PhonePK();
    phonePK.setPhoneNumber("1111111111");
    phonePK.setStudent(student); // Do not do this? But won't work (id cannot be null  
    error) if
                                 // commented out??
    phone.setPK(phonePK);
    phones.add(phone);

    student.setPhones(phones);

    try {
        transaction = session.beginTransaction();
        System.out.println(student.toString()); // stackoverflow error!
        session.save(student);
        transaction.commit();
    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        transaction.rollback();
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It is happening because of the way you have defined toString() methods

Student's `toString()` is invoking Phone's `toString()` which is invoking PhonePK's `toString()` which in turn is invoking Student's `toString()`...causing infinite loop.

Let see how it is happening in detailed way

In Student `toString()` because of `phones` instance variable in it .it will iterate through each phone and call Phone `toString()`

```
public String toString() {
    return String.format("Student [id=%s, fname=%s, lname=%s, mname=%s, phones=%s]",      
id,
        fName, lName, mName, phones);
}
```

In Phone `toString()` because of `PK` instance variable in it .it will invoke PhonePK `toString()`

```
public String toString() {
    return String.format("Phone [PK=%s, color=%s]", PK, color);
}
```

In PhonePK `toString()` because of `phoneNumber` instance variable in it .it will invoke Phone `toString()`

```
public String toString() {
    return String.format("PhonePK [student=%s, phoneNumber=%s]", student, phoneNumber);
}
```

Comment: Ok, thank you.. I corrected it. Removed the student instance variable from PhonePK toString method. But is there a way I can avoid the circular reference all together? I don't want to do student.setPhones and phone.setStudent both. Shouldn't hibernate take care of this?